# @OneToMany relation hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi everyone I have entities:

Child:
@EDIT thanks to @MithatKonuk

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="FirstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="SecondName")
    private String secondName;

    @Column(name="PESEL")
    private String PESEL;

    @Column(name="Sex")
    private String sex;

  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="familyid",referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Family family;
```

And Family:@EDIT thanks to @MithatKonuk

```
@Entity
@Table(name="family")
public class Family {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;



    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Father father;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "family",fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> childList;
```

And I want to get List of children which be a part of family. I tried make query:
@EDIT thanks to @MithatKonuk

```
@Transactional
public List<Child> findAllChild(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HibernateUtil.initManager();
    HibernateUtil.getEntityManager().clear();
    Query query = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT child FROM Child child FETCH JOIN child.family u WHERE u.id = :userId ");
    query.setParameter("userId",id);
    List<Child> result = query.getResultList();
    HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    return result;
}
```

And when I try run it I always get error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "all", found 'JOIN' near line 1, column 64 [SELECT child FROM com.example.Family3.domain.Child child FETCH JOIN child.family u WHERE u.id = :userId ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:296) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:704) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.5.Final.jar:5.3.5.Final]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I need your help.

@Edit Ok so I updated this code to full entities. Do you need some more? 
I'm so sorry maybe it's easy but I learning hibernate and I don't know what's wrong is in this cos. Thanks for answer.

Comment: your query also wrong add all your code here

Comment: Check this part `JOIN di.Family`. Are you sure that you need `di` here?

Comment: @talex thanks for answer. I change this part without it but I've got error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!

Comment: Try `JOIN di.family u`. Unlike SQL in HQL it require field, not class name.

Comment: try "SELECT di FROM Child di JOIN Family f WHERE di.id = :userId ".

Comment: @talex I don't have an error but queryresult get always 0.

Comment: CRISTIAN ROMERO MATESANZ it's not working.

Comment: @luksen1991 it hard to tell why. Try to log SQL generated by hibernate and execute it manually. It may give you a hint about what is going on.

Comment: @MithatKonuk I've get error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "all", found 'JOIN'

Comment: change like this join fetch  i just wrote wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to change your query

```
@Transactional
public List<Child> findAllChild(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HibernateUtil.initManager();
    HibernateUtil.getEntityManager().clear();
    Query query = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT child FROM Child child JOIN FETCH child.family  WHERE child.family.id = :userId ");
    query.setParameter("userId",id);
    List<Child> result = query.getResultList();
    HibernateUtil.shutdown();
    return result;
}
```

Second one is please add @Entity and @Table("child") and @Table("family") to each classes as seen below

```
@Entity
@Table("child table name")
public class Child{}

@Entity
@Table("family table name")
public class Family{}
```

Answer (score 0):

JOIN should be before FETCH, try this query:

```
"SELECT child FROM Child child JOIN FETCH child.family WHERE child.family.id = :userId"
```